# android JSONException while trying to parse JSON data

Tags: android, json, exception

I use the class below to get some JSON data. The strange thing is, I can't parse JSON only from the url I need to test the app (server-side not maintained by me): if you click on [this link](http://vm2156.dunkel.de/radioappservice/rest/metadata/content/votes/hr1/null), you will be able to see JSON data in your browser. But when I try to parse it programmatically, it throws a JSONException.

```
  01-03 11:08:23.615: E/JSON Parser(19668): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:    Value <html><head><title>JBoss of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I tried to test it with http://ip.jsontest.com/  and http://api.androidhive.info/contacts, **it works nicely**! Exception is only thrown while trying to parse JSON from my 1st link. I thought it could be a server problem, but I'm able to see JSON data with a browser.. just can't explain that.

```
   public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

/* default constuctor*/
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

   /* get JSON via http request */
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    /* try to parse the string to JSON Object*/
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

 /* return JSON String */
    return jObj;

      }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you're actually getting a JBoss error message.  I'd add a `System.err.println(json);` to see what you're actually trying to parse...

Comment: Your problem is in  jObj = new JSONObject(json); , check if your string 'json' contains any weird signs or html.

Comment: yep... value <html><head><title>.......... But why?

Comment: Does this site accept POST, or just GET.  I would try a `HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url)`, as this is how our browsers are retrieving the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the BufferedReader approach will fetch you the HTML source of that page, which is why you see HTML tags like < html>< head>< title> in your string. Instead, use EntityUtils to get the JSON string:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: when I tried ..... In jsonString  ::>>> I am not getting the whole data ... di you know how to manage it ?

Comment: ,
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zUaMzFrRLWg/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width...  "In the end i got "..." how to get whole data "